# Find all the zeroes over a diagonal of a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't know if this question has been asked before so I wanted to go ahead and post it. 
I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
YEAR    CountyCode         C01   C02 C03 C04 C05 C06 . . .  
2012    C01                132    0   3   1   4   9 
2012    C02                 0    21   0   57  0   0 
2012    C03                 0    0   56   0  1    1
2012    C04                 0    6    0  40 0    26 
2012    C06                 0    0    1   0  0    0 
2012    C07                 0    0    1  32  219  6
.        .      
.        .
.        .
2013    C01                220    9   2   4   0   0 
2013    C02                 0    54   0   62  0   2 
2013    C03                 0    0   24   0   1   1
2013    C04                 0    6    0  224  0   2 
2013    C06                 0    0    2   0   0   0 
2013    C07                 0    0    1  37   2   3
```

And so on for 5 years of data. Each year is associated with 75 columns with entries "C0x" associated with a specific "C0x" under county code. Basically its sort of a payer matrix.

All the rows under CountyCode are correct (there are about 65 correct ones) while the vertical columns are not all correct. There are very specific county codes (for example, 1,2,3,4,6 and so on).

So as you can see C05 doesn't match a C05 because it doesn't actually exist, and there is a break on the diagonal. Because the table format was made so that anyone can use it, the person who entered in the values obviously made major errors.

The only goal is to find all values on the *diagonal* where the columns are incorrect and break the diagonal. I want to weed out these. for example., under C05 (column) and row C06 (under County Code) is zero for 2012-2016. The output can just be a simple list like this : `[1] C05,C40, ...` so I can find these outliers and better position them.

The point is to find the wrong counties in the columns.

PS: There are about 65 (rows) x 75 (columns) *for each year* and while I can try doing it manually, I would like to code it up so that it can be used further.

Thank you!

Comment: You could reshape to long the c0* columns, then you will have 3 columns which should contain every combination of years and both county codes, fill in the rows that are missing (eg, `2012 C05 C01 NA`, `2012 C05 C02 NA`, etc), then reshape back to wide

Comment: @rawr Thanks but the rows are actually correct ones. The people who have entered values in the columns (and even column names) have made mistakes. Ideally the dataframe should be 65x65 for each year. If I can find those that are actually not matching across the diagonal, I can report back so that they can make changes. This table is the end result of an aggregation on an aggregation on a table that has been spread twice (in so many multiple steps) that its hard for me to tweak every value. Reporting back, the 100s of agencies who filled incorrectly can take note and send me updated files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution using the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, .(cols_not_in_rows = setdiff(names(.SD)[-1], CountyCode),
       rows_not_in_cols = setdiff(CountyCode, names(.SD)[-1]))
   , by = YEAR]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    YEAR cols_not_in_rows rows_not_in_cols
> 1: 2012              C05              C07
> 2: 2013              C05              C07
> ```

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L),
                     CountyCode = c("C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C06", "C07", "C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C06", "C07"),
                     C01 = c(132L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 220L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                     C02 = c(0L, 21L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 54L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L),
                     C03 = c(3L, 0L, 56L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 2L, 1L),
                     C04 = c(1L, 57L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 32L, 4L, 62L, 0L, 224L, 0L, 37L),
                     C05 = c(4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 219L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L),
                     C06 = c(9L, 0L, 1L, 26L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L)),
                .Names = c("YEAR", "CountyCode", "C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", "C06"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In base R, to see which columns are not in `df$CountyCode`, you can do

```
names(df[,c(-1,-2)])[!(names(df[,c(-1,-2)]) %in% df$CountyCode)]
```

If you just want to retain the columns that are in `df$CountyCode` perhaps you can do something like

```
library(tidyverse)
correct <- names(df[,c(-1,-2)])[names(df[,c(-1,-2)]) %in% df$CountyCode]
df %>% select(1,2, correct)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$YEAR), function(x){
  Column = as.matrix(x[,-(1:2)])
  Row = x$CountyCode
  data.frame(Column = colnames(Column)[diag(Column) == 0],
             Row = Row[diag(Column) == 0])
}))
```

**Result:**

```
     Column Row
2012    C05 C06
2013    C05 C06
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L),
                     CountyCode = c("C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C06", "C07", "C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C06", "C07"),
                     C01 = c(132L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 220L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
                     C02 = c(0L, 21L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 54L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L),
                     C03 = c(3L, 0L, 56L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 2L, 1L),
                     C04 = c(1L, 57L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 32L, 4L, 62L, 0L, 224L, 0L, 37L),
                     C05 = c(4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 219L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L),
                     C06 = c(9L, 0L, 1L, 26L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 3L)),
                .Names = c("YEAR", "CountyCode", "C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", "C06"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thank you but its weirdly posting the missing, as well as some non missing values, under the 'column' column for the result.

Comment: Well, all this does is return all rows and columns corresponding to diagonals that are zero, so I'm not sure what you mean by "posting the missing, as well as some non missing values". Perhaps update your sample dataset to better reflect your real data?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean it shows this under the Column:  `[1] C05 C06...`  I'll change the problem statement to reflect that I only want the specific county columns that are wrongly entered/created.